# Нарисовать поворачивающийся "подсолнух " в паскаль

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Задание «Подсолнух» - нарисовать подсолнух и солнце на небосклоне. солнце
движется слева направо по верху экрана, а цветок подсолнуха
вращается за ним.
Я написал такую программу:

```
program test;

uses
  crt,
  graphABC;

var
  x: integer;
begin
  while x < 640 do
  begin
    Window.Clear;
    setpencolor(clyellow);
    setBrushColor(clyellow);
    circle(x, 100, 50);
    Setpencolor(clgreen);
    Setpenwidth(4);
    Line(300, 330, 300, 400);
    Line(300, 400, 330, 330);
    Line(300, 400, 280, 330);
    Setpencolor(clyellow);
    setBrushColor(clorange);
    circle(300, 300, 30);
    x := x + 5;
    delay(100);
  end;
end.
```

Но у меня проблема.Я смог нарисовать солнце которое движется и стебель с цветком.Но я не знаю как сделать так, чтоб цветок подсолнуха двигался за солнцем. Мне написали, что

> нужно использовать для подсолнуха вместо процедуры круга: procedure
>   Ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2: integer); Рисует заполненный прямоугольник,
>   заданный координатами противоположных вершин (x1,y1) и (x2,y2) -
>   сделать уменьшение (сужение) прямоугольника, в который вписывается
>   эллипс, по Х (х1 и х2 - уменьшать в цикле)  и тогда будет иллюзия
>   поворота подсолнуха

. Но я все равно не понимаю как это сделать. Кто знает помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Какие должны быть рассуждения:

Когда солнце близко, то круг максимальный, солнце далеко - цветок боком, то есть одна линия. Чтобы узнать на сколько поворачивается цветок необходимо рассчитать коэффициент подобия, не забываем что рассматриваем половину пути и не допускаем обнуления (уменьшаем диаметр на один) получается `29 / (640 /2)`. Координата `x` у нас просто возрастает, а диаметр сначала увеличивается затем уменьшается, я просто сместил начало координат для цветка.

В итоге

```
var
  s: integer;
...
s := 30 - Round((29 / (640 / 2)) * Abs(x - (640 / 2)));
Ellipse(300 - s, 300 - 30, 300 + s, 300 + 30);
```

Никак не упрощал, не вводил перменные, чтобы было понятно.